# In html5 can you have an <h1> in a footer

Tags: html, footer

I've looked all over and have yet to find anything that specifically answers this question: In html5 is it semantically ok to have an h1 tag inside of a footer? I know that you can have multiple h1s in a document now but I'm working on a project that involves a footer with a heading and there's some debate going on as to whether or not that is semantic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing mutually exclusive about `footer` and `h1` tags. In fact, you can even have multiple footers, too.

Take a look at W3C HTML standard last code example for [footer](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-footer-element): it contains `h1` inside of one:

> Some site designs have what is sometimes referred to as "fat footers"
>   — footers that contain a lot of material, including images, links to
>   other articles, links to pages for sending feedback, special offers...
>   in some ways, a whole "front page" in the footer.
>
> This fragment shows the bottom of a page on a site with a "fat
>   footer":

```
...
 <footer>
  <nav>
   <section>
    <h1>Articles</h1>
    ...
```

Comment: Great answer, a little more in-depth and with a code example. It would be great to find some official documentation that references this; I'm sure it's out there somewhere, I'll keep looking.

Comment: Yep, just reread your comment and caught W3C link; thanks for the awesome answer!

Comment: Can I have the only H1 header in the footer that can be found at the end of the page? H1 should be on the site because of SEO, but this would spoil the appearance of the project. It is better not to hide it but I thought that it could be put somewhere below. I would like to add that I have many H2 headings and placing H1 under them seems to me no sense.

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that in your example and link it the `h1` in the footer is always wrapped inside a `<section></section>` tag.

`<section>` can have its own blocks of self contained content as well

```html
<header>
    <!-- nav/logo/etc -->
</header>
<main>
    <!-- article/content/section/etc -->
</main>
<footer>
    <!-- nav/links/section/etc... -->
    <section>
        <h1></h1> <!-- h1 in a NEW section -->
    </section>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Semantically this would be very bad as H1 are for representing a header for a section or whatever. Image this for a blind user. There is a discussion on this here:

http://moz.com/community/q/h1-tag-in-the-footer

Comment: What if a section of whatever is located in a footer?

Comment: That is an old discussion, looking for some more up to date information.

Comment: Then it should not be in a footer

Comment: The footer element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element. A footer typically contains information about its section such as who wrote it, links to related documents, copyright data, and the like. Footers don’t necessarily have to appear at the end of a section, though they usually do. When the footer element contains entire sections, they represent appendices, indexes, long colophons, verbose license agreements, and other such content.

Comment: @EugeneXa With respect to Jay, this is not correct (referring to the comment "then it should not be in a footer". In html5 you can have sections in a footer; it seems like there's a lot more freedom with html5 than there used to be so a lot of people are uncomfortable with certain aspects of said freedom and so stick to what they know and are comfortable with. This link answers your question: http://html5doctor.com/your-questions-answered-10/